# Preference between call and bind in javascript?

Tags: javascript, call, bind

Following code gives the output `{name:'xyz'}`.
How do we know what this points to when both call and bind are used?

```
var factoryFunc = function() {
    console.log(this);
}.bind({
    'name': 'xyz'
})

factoryFunc.call({
    'name': 'abc'
})
```

Comment: i wouldn't say it's a duplicate, OP is asking about chaining function calls, and which context has precedence

Answer (score 0):

A bound function will have its `this` value immutable. So in your case the `XYZ` object will be pointed.

I will update this answer when I get to my pc